# How to synchronize scrolling of a textbox and listbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox, scroll

I want to design a textbox which has index of each line on a separate list-box beside itself.everything is almost done but scrolling is still a problem for me.when I use `WndProc` to control scrolling, `WM_VSCROLL` works very well and makes both control scroll in same time,but when I want to send `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` via List-box,it doesn't work.I thought I can use a trick and iterate `WM_VSCROLL` when user moves mouse wheel but It doesn't work too.

```
    private const int WM_VSCROLL = 0x115;
    private const int WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x20A;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);            
        if (m.Msg == WM_VSCROLL )
        {
            Message newMessage = Message.Create(Sequence.Handle, m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam);
            Sequence.DirectMessage(newMessage);//turn to thread
        }
        else if(m.Msg == WM_MOUSEWHEEL)
        {
            if((int)m.WParam<0)
            {

                Message newMessage = Message.Create(Sequence.Handle, WM_VSCROLL,(IntPtr)1,(IntPtr) 0);
                Message newMessage2 = Message.Create(this.Handle, WM_VSCROLL, (IntPtr)1, (IntPtr)0);                    
                Sequence.DirectMessage(newMessage);
                base.WndProc(ref newMessage2);
            }
            else
            {
                Message newMessage = Message.Create(Sequence.Handle, WM_VSCROLL, (IntPtr)0, (IntPtr)0);
                Message newMessage2 = Message.Create(this.Handle, WM_VSCROLL, (IntPtr)0, (IntPtr)0);
                Sequence.DirectMessage(newMessage);
                base.WndProc(ref newMessage2);
            }
        }
    }
```

`Sequence` is the name of my list-box and `this` infers to my textbox.I would appreciate any kind of help... .

Answer (score 0):

Do the same as `WM_SCROLL`:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]
internal static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

private const int WM_VSCROLL = 0x115;
private const int WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x20A;

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_VSCROLL || m.Msg == WM_MOUSEWHEEL)
    {
        SendMessage(Sequence.Handle, (UInt32)m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam);
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```